# Emacs: What do `mouse-1`, `mouse-2` buttons etc. mean?

Tags: emacs

Where are the following buttons located on my mouse?

**EDIT:** I have added locations in brackets after answer by Jack.

- `mouse-1` (Left button)
- `mouse-2` (Wheel button click / Middle button)
- `mouse-3` (Right button)
- `mouse-4` (Wheel up)
- `mouse-5` (Wheel down)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the different (potential) buttons on a mouse.

You can see which is which by doing <kbd>C-h c</kbd> and then clicking a mouse button.